# lazy loading asp.net core angular2

Tags: angular, asp.net5

I'm developing a web api using asp.net core.
the web api return a json array and my angular2 client display it in a table. My probleme is that if i have 10.000 items in the array I want not to load it all to the client , instead I want to implement a pagination system that load data .

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the help menu about what questions to ask or not to ask and how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best thing to do in your case since you don't want to pull in all the data at once, is to have a "pageNum" that you send to the .net back-end to get the data. So, you'd have something like this. (Using SQL)

```
SELECT * FROM my_table limit [start], 50 
// this will get the next 50 rows after the start number 
// (IE: if start is 100, it'll get 101 - 150)
```

`start` would need to be a variable that is equal to `pageNum * 50` in this case. And then you just send the result.

I don't know .net, so I can't give you specific syntax, but that's how I would go about it.